# Pass content from a datagridview to another datagridview using a button

Tags: vb.net

Good day.
I am trying to pass all the content of a datagridview from the child form to another datagridview from the parent form in the following way.
[image]

---

I have managed to pass the data through the gridview button, but this time it is only passing me 1 record but I am trying to pass all the records of that datadriview

This is my code that I have implemented.

child form

```
 Private Function BuscarProductos() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Try
     
            dt.Columns.Add("IDPRODUCTO")
            dt.Columns.Add("DESCRIPCION")
        dt.Rows.Add(If(IsDBNull(dgvdetalleproduc.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value), "", dgvdetalleproduc.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value),
                        If(IsDBNull(dgvdetalleproduc.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value), "", dgvdetalleproduc.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value))

    Catch ex1 As SqlClient.SqlException : MessageBox.Show(ex1.Message, "AUTONORT S.A.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    Catch ex As Exception : MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "AUTONORT S.A.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
    Return dt
End Function
```

add button

```
 Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim _dataTable As DataTable = BuscarProductos()

    Dim estadoOperacion As Boolean = Me.Openerproducs.BusquedadProduct(_dataTable)
    'e.Cancel = Not estadoOperacion


    Me.Close()


End Sub
```

and in the parent form it receives it with this method

```
Public Function BusquedadPRODUC(ByVal dataTableParam As DataTable) As Boolean Implements IFormProduc.BusquedadProduct 'BUSCAR POr afiliado
    Try

        dgvdetalle.Rows.Add(dataTableParam.Rows(0).Item(0), dataTableParam.Rows(0).Item(1))


        'Me.dgvdetalle.Columns.Add(dataTableParam.Rows(0).Item(0))
        ' txtnomproducto.Text = dataTableParam.Rows(0).Item(1)

        'dgvMantenimiento.Rows.Add(dataTableParam.Rows(0).Item(0), dataTableParam.Rows(0).Item(1))
        'txtCliente.Text = 

        'dgvRequerimiento.Rows.Add(If(dgvRequerimiento.Rows(dgvRequerimiento.Rows.Count - 1).Cells(0).Value + 1 <= 9, "00" + (dgvRequerimiento.Rows(dgvRequerimiento.Rows.Count - 1).Cells(0).Value + 1).ToString, "0" + (dgvRequerimiento.Rows(dgvRequerimiento.Rows.Count - 1).Cells(0).Value + 1).ToString), rows.Item(2), rows.Item(3), rows.Item(4), rows.Item(6), rows.Item(5))




        'Dim formAdd As New frmLineaCredito
        'formAdd.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent
        'formAdd.Opener = CType(Me, IFormVH)
        'formAdd.Text = "Linea de Credito : " + VGlobales.Empresa
        'formAdd.frmLineaCredito(lblCodigoClie.Text.Trim)
        'formAdd.Show()

    Catch ex1 As SqlClient.SqlException : MessageBox.Show(ex1.Message, "hola", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    Catch ex As Exception : MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "hola", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
    Return True
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Firstly, how is the parent form opening the child, i.e. are you calling `Show` or `ShowDialog`? Secondly, is the child form to remain open after the data is transferred or is it closing at that point? You should almost certainly be creating a `DataTable` and binding that to the child grid, then either passing that `DataTable` or a copy of it back to the parent but the specifics of how you'd do that depend on the questions I asked.

Comment: edit my question to your question

Comment: So both forms are MDI children of the same parent, right? In that case, the "proper" way to do it is for the source child to raise an event, the parent to handle that event, the parent to pull the data from the source child, the parent to push the data to the destination child and the destination child to update its own grid. Once you confirmed that I have the scenario correct, I'll post an answer with an example of that solution.

Comment: True, they would both be children but let's say that the one who calls the child is the eldest child and the one who has the grids the youngest, yes of course I have been killing myself for days how to pass the data from the grid painted green to the eldest child, thank you.

Comment: For the time being, you might like to check out my three-part blog post on [Managing Data Among Multiple Forms](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2012/04/managing-data-among-multiple-forms-part.html). It will provide you all the information you need to be able to handle any scenario. I'll provide a specific example but all the principles used will be in that blog post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example of what I described in the comments above. `Form1` creates and displays two MDI children. One of those child forms raises an event on the `Click` of a `Button` that the parent form handles. The parent then pulls the data from that child, pushes it to the other child and then the second child displays that data.

Parent:

```vb
Public Class Form1

    'Source child form
    Private WithEvents f2 As Form2

    'Destination child form
    Private f3 As Form3

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        f2 = New Form2
        f2.MdiParent = Me
        f2.Show()

        f3 = New Form3
        f3.MdiParent = Me
        f3.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub f2_DataAvailable(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles f2.DataAvailable
        'Pull data from source
        Dim table = f2.GetData()

        'Push data to destination
        f3.SetData(table)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Source child:

```vb
Public Class Form2

    Private table As DataTable

    Public Event DataAvailable As EventHandler

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        table = New DataTable()

        With table.Columns
            .Add("Number", GetType(Integer))
            .Add("Text", GetType(String))
        End With

        BindingSource1.DataSource = table
        DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        OnDataAvailable(EventArgs.Empty)
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub OnDataAvailable(e As EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent DataAvailable(Me, e)
    End Sub

    Public Function GetData() As DataTable
        Return table.Copy()
    End Function

End Class
```

Destination child:

```vb
Public Class Form3

    Public Sub SetData(table As DataTable)
        BindingSource1.DataSource = table
        DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
    End Sub

End Class
```

You can test that code for yourself very easily. Just create a project with three form, make the first an MDI parent, add a `DataGridView`, a `BindingSource` and a `Button` to the second and a `DataGridView` and a `BindingSource` to the third and you're good to go.